# Stream a video from FFmpeg to Wowza with subtitles

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, subtitles, flv, rtmp

I need to stream a video **with subtitles** from FFmpeg to a Wowza server. What stream protocol and video format can I use?

I was using the FLV video format on a RTMP stream but I think it does not support subtitles (I did not find how anyway).

I precise that I don't want to burn the subtitles in the video.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Wowza has support for different closed captioning input sources, depending on the input type. Please refer to the documentation for [live streaming](https://www.wowza.com/docs/how-to-configure-closed-captioning-for-live-streaming) and [VOD](https://www.wowza.com/docs/how-to-configure-closed-captioning-for-video-on-demand-streaming).

Particularly for FLV there used to be software to inject subtitles, but it's not directly available anymore.

Wowza also has an API which you can use to insert raw text as subtitles into live streams, including an [example of how to use it](https://www.wowza.com/docs/how-to-configure-closed-captioning-for-live-streaming#publishing_ontextdata).

Comment: That said you may be better off asking in the [Wowza forums](https://www.wowza.com/community/index.html)